# Errors when opening Microsoft office

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

The installation process was successful but I get error messages when opening any application. The instructions I followed were from [here](http://www.jonathanmoeller.com/screed/?p=1656). How do I go about it? I am using Ubuntu 10.04. The error message I get is

```
Unhandled exception: assertion failed in 32-bit code (0x6b02b832).
Register dump:
 CS:0073 SS:007b DS:007b ES:007b FS:0033 GS:003b
 EIP:6b02b832 ESP:0033e6e4 EBP:0033e6f0 EFLAGS:00200202(   - --  I   - - - )
 EAX:00000000 EBX:00000f0b ECX:00000f0b EDX:00000006
 ESI:6828ba9e EDI:682aeff4
Stack dump:
0x0033e6e4:  68184651 682aeff4 0033e810 0033e818
0x0033e6f4:  68187a82 00000006 0033e790 00000000
0x0033e704:  0001ee00 682b0450 00000090 682b03c0
0x0033e714:  682aeff4 682b03c0 0000008a 0033e738
0x0033e724:  681c9a9d 0033e800 682aeff4 682aeff4
0x0033e734:  0000008b 0033e800 681b9da8 7db7b0d8
Backtrace:
=>0 0x6b02b832 GLIBC_2+0x832() in ld-linux.so.2 (0x0033e6f0)
  1 0x68187a82 abort+0x181() in libc.so.6 (0x0033e818)
  2 0x6817d718 __assert_fail+0xf7() in libc.so.6 (0x0033e860)
  3 0x712fec66 in riched20 (+0xec65) (0x0033e930)
  4 0x71310688 in riched20 (+0x20687) (0x0033e9e0)
  5 0x7130bee1 in riched20 (+0x1bee0) (0x0033eaa0)
  6 0x7130c21c in riched20 (+0x1c21b) (0x0033ead0)
  7 0x6d3b9a9a WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x0033eb00)
```

Comment: I hate saying this, but did you search Google for this? [Here](http://www.jonathanmoeller.com/screed/?p=1656) is the first result, which should get you on your way to using Office 2007 on Ubuntu 10.04. :)

Comment: That said, I had best experience with running MS Office inside a Windows 7 copy on a virtual box machine. Nice integration with the Linux desktop, no compatibility problems.

Comment: Here's an [additional link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/183581/ms-word-2007-crashing-at-exit) that may help you, should difficulties arise with Wine.

Comment: @Sircharlo, i tried using the first link you sent to. the installation was successful but none of the application is opening.

Comment: Try opening an app (for example Word) using the Terminal, and post any errors you get in your original question (**edit it**).

Comment: @SirCharlo, i have posted it you can have a look please

Comment: Try upgrading your Wine using the Ubuntu Wine PPA.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you with your problem, but I had a similar problem with installing games on Ubuntu and got a similar error. My suggestion to you, and thing that worked fo me is, try updating your graphics driver.

Hope this helps!